# Как сделать несколько option в select и достать их значение и вывести в ячейки в таблице?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

как сделать несколько value значений в option из select и достать их значение и вывести в ячейки в таблице ? При выборе страны из select во всех ячейках меняется цена услуги.. Спасибо большое за любою помощь.

```css
table {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 3rem;
    }

    table tbody tr td span {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: initial;
    }

    td {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .tbody-gray {
        background-color: #00BFFF;
    }

    .tbody-blue {
        background-color: #BA55D3;
    }

    .tbody-green {
        background-color: #00FF7F;
    }

    .td-heading {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: .5rem;
    }
```

```html
<select name="countries" id="countries">
       <option>Country</option>
       <option value="1">Argentina</option>
       <option value="2">Australia</option>
       <option value="3">Austria</option>
</select>
 <table>
            <tbody class="tbody-gray">
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-heading">Price One</td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-one">$25.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-two">$75.30<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-three">$15.30<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
             <tbody class="tbody-blue">
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-heading">Price Two</td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-four">$5.90<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-five">$3.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-six">$1.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
             <tbody class="tbody-green">
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-heading">Price Three</td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-seven">$35.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-eight">$15.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                        <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-nine">$45.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если значений не много можно вписать их в html, подразумевая заполнение ячеек по порядку...

```js
let s = document.querySelector('#countries');
let cost = document.querySelectorAll('.cost-numbers')

s.onchange = function(e) {
  if (this.selectedIndex) {
    let m = this.value.split(',')
    cost.forEach((e, i) => {
      e.innerHTML = '$' + m[i] + '<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo'
    })
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

table tbody tr td span {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: initial;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.tbody-gray {
  background-color: #00BFFF;
}

.tbody-blue {
  background-color: #BA55D3;
}

.tbody-green {
  background-color: #00FF7F;
}

.td-heading {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<select name="countries" id="countries">
  <option>Country</option>
  <option value="10.89,20.67,30.76,11.56,29.45,38.22,17.33,26.78,35.34">Argentina</option>
  <option value="88.89,99.45,95.89,45.45,55.99,65.89,75.75,85.25,34.15">Australia</option>
  <option value="44.89,51.89,20.45,21.15,22.15,23.18,24.45,25.12,26.11">Austria</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tbody class="tbody-gray">
    <tr>
      <td class="td-heading">Price One</td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-one">$25.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-two">$75.30<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-three">$15.30<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="tbody-blue">
    <tr>
      <td class="td-heading">Price Two</td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-four">$5.90<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-five">$3.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-six">$1.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="tbody-green">
    <tr>
      <td class="td-heading">Price Three</td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-seven">$35.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-eight">$15.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="cost-numbers" id="cost-nine">$45.60<span class="cost-conditions"></span>/mo</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А если значений будет много только массив ?

Comment: Если много, лучше на бэк отправлять значение выбранного `option`. Хранить всё в бд, или в файле на сервере, отправлять данные на фронт, из них уже строить таблицу.. Строка из `value` подразумевает массив, просто на символах `[ ]` "сэкономлено", можно в виде массива записать и парсить строку, вместо разбиения `split`-ом..